# form_validation->run() not properly working

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
 public function upload()
    {
        if (empty($_FILES['vchr_file']['name'])) {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('vchr_file','File','required');
        }

        if ($this->form_validation->run()== true) 
        {
            echo 'valid';
        }
        else{

    $data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : ($this->ion_auth->errors() ? $this->ion_auth->errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message')));


            $data['file']=array(
                        'name'  =>'vchr_file',
                        'type'  =>'file',
                        'label' =>'File Upload'
                        );

            $this->load->user_view('kyc',$data);
        }   
    }
```

my controller

```
div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <?php echo form_label($file['label']); 
                     echo form_input($file); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

my view

the form_validation never run true.. and also when i upload a file the validation error not showing,but validation run() not working.

Comment: if you don't set any rules, run will return false

Comment: Show the rest of the view file - at least the part containing the form

Comment: It's not normal to validate files with form validation. The Upload class handles validation of files.

Comment: @BrianGottier it isn't but I've seen this "hack" before and it does work especially if you want to keep everything within the validation library

Comment: @Alex, while you might have seen it, it's a bad practice. The Upload class has specific security measures related to file uploads. It can utilize true file type detection, and is the right tool for the job (unless security isn't an issue). One would have to go out of their way and code up a bunch of stuff to make the Form_validation class work well for file uploads. Just open up the classes and see for yourself. They are not similar.

Comment: I'm very aware of the differences between the two library's and I'm not saying that form validation library should be jerry-rigged to work as a rudimentary mime detector .etc. I was simply stating that for face-value form validation where you want to merely check if the field is uploaded, this isn't all that bad of an option as all the errors will be contained within the form_validation error array making it easier to handle. with that being said this will obviously not account for issues related to wrong file type upload .etc. but that can be handled further down the chain.

Answer (score 0):

When the file is actually uploaded the conditional `set_rules` statement doesn't apply the rule (which makes sense). However, `form_validation` always requires a rule to be set, if no rules are set (e.g. the conditional statement never goes through because a file is uploaded), than `run()` will always return false.

If you are planning on implementing more rules you shouldn't have a problem.

It is preferred to just handle it without `form_validation` and just a conditional statement with `empty($_FILES['vchr_file']['name']` (again, if you aren't adding more rules).